# ngtable how to remove title centered

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to work on ngTable, and i find it ugly to put Title of column in midle by standard... how can we put the title to the left like the text of the row?

Here is the html code:

```
        <table ng-table class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="survey in vm.surveys">
                <td data-title="'@L("Name")'">{{survey.name}}</td>
                <td data-title="'@L("CreatedDate")'">{{survey.creationTime}}</td>
                <td data-title="'@L("Creator")'">{{survey.creatorUser}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Is this a css-question, like in `text-align: left`?

Comment: <td data-title="'@L("Name")'" style="text-align: left;">{{survey.name}}</td> but it didn't work at all.. it still stay in the middle because we are trying to affect the CSS to the data-row not the header row

Comment: Found it by your CSS word! i didnt check my html source... i did found it in 2seconds after i wrote my comment... it's included by default in the CSS of ng-table! thx for pointing out CSS i was not paying attention to CSS

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following CSS rule:

```
.ng-table th { text-align: left; }
```